# Linux binary serial read issue

Tags: c, linux, binary, serial-port

I have put together some code to try and read a binary stream across a serial port in Linux (ubuntu).  It is behaving oddly, dropping a portion of the data:

Code:

```
int nNeed;
PBYTE pChar = (PBYTE) malloc(1024*4096*sizeof(BYTE));
int nRead = 0;


int SRL = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK );

struct termios tty;
struct termios tty_old;
memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

// Error Handling 
if ( tcgetattr ( SRL, &tty ) != 0 ) 
{
   printf("\n ERROR: %d, %s \n", errno, strerror(errno));
}

// Save old tty parameters 
tty_old = tty;

// Set Baud Rate
cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B57600);
cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B57600);

// Setting other Port Stuff, MAKE 8n1
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;

tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  1;                 
tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  1;                  
tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

// Make raw 
//cfmakeraw(&tty);

tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF |IXANY);

// Flush Port, then applies attributes 
tcflush( SRL, TCIFLUSH );
if ( tcsetattr ( SRL, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0) 
{
     printf("\n ERROR: %d, %s \n", errno, strerror(errno));
}

int count = 0;
int noread_cnt = 0;
nNeed = 1024;

while(1) 
{
    count++;

    //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_comm);
    nRead = read(SRL, pChar, nNeed);
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_comm);

    if(nRead > 0) 
    {
        printf("\n Read: %d    ", nRead);
        for (int i = 0; i < nRead; i++)
        {
            //printf("\n IN: (nRead) ");
            //printf("%02x  ",*pChar++);
            printf("%02x  ",pChar[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else if (nRead < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN)
        {
            // Not real error, read again
            noread_cnt++;

            if (noread_cnt == 19200*100)
            {
                printf("EAGAIN\n");
                noread_cnt = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n nREad: %d, ERROR: %d, %s \n", nRead, errno, strerror(errno) );
        }
    }

    sleep(0);
}

return NULL;
```

A ramp is being sent: 00 11 22 3 44 55 66 77 88 99 aa bb cc dd ee ff

(that is sent via a coworker's test app that is known to work).

My code's output is as follows:

Read: 3    11 22 33

Read: 3    55 66 77

Read: 3    99 aa bb

Read: 3    dd ee ff

My code seems to have dropped the first byte of a line of four bytes, the 00, 44, 88, and cc bytes.

I'm a newbie to linux, so I assume I've set up the port wrong somehow.  However, I can't seem to find the problem.  Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably should have the C tag to get help.

Comment: Other than posting incomplete code that generates an error (`‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode`) and various warnings, your code seems to work as expected.  You should remove that C99 requirement, and then re-evaluate that *"coworker's test app that is known to work"*.  E.G. replace it with a terminal emulation program and type in chars or send a short file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.  I had a getty running on the serial port.  I went to /etc/init/ and found ttyS0.conf file.  Inside it, it stated it was running a getty, so I commented out all lines.  When I rebooted my code worked fine.  I do realized, however, now I have no default serial console terminal unless I uncomment the getty instructions.

Sawdust and Jim, thank you for your comments.